# How to change male box shape in genealogytree package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, genealogytree

In genealogytree package both male and female use the box of same kind of shape how do i change the box shape of male box from rectangle rounded corners to rectangle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The settings are stored in the `tcolorbox` keys `male` and `female`. You can set them globally with `tcbset{ ... }`. This is discussed on p. 99  of the `genealogytree` manual, but the actual `tcolorbox` options themselves (most of which are plain TikZ options) you will need to look either in the `tcolorbox` manual or the TikZ manual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\tcbset{male/.style={colframe=red,sharp corners},female/.style={colframe=blue,rounded corners}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost,male={red},female={blue}]{ parent{
        g[male]{first child}
        c[female]{second child}
        c[female]{third child}
        p[male]{father}
        p[female]{mother}
}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]